# Where MemoryStream writes data

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm asking this question just because of curiosity. Where is  the data written in a  [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) goes?
This link tells,

**Creates a stream whose backing store is memory.**

I have to ask, what type of memory is it? Is it RAM or ROM ? I searched on the google but found no straight answers. Everywhere I look it says data is written in memory but no one clearly talks about the type of memory.

Comment: ROM (Read-Only Memory) cannot be wrote when you run a program, isn't it?

Comment: "memory" is pretty much synonymous with RAM, at least when talking about a standard desktop PC.

Comment: Stop thinking of RAM as memory; RAM hasn't been the relevant measure of memory *associated with a process* for decades. Memory is better imagined as a vast file on disk, portions of which are copied into RAM to make them faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is stored in RAM, on the heap. Each process that runs on Windows gets its own virtual address space of memory in RAM. Part of that memory is used to store the instructions of the process, and part is for the heap and the stack which are the sections of memory your program uses to store variables.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand a lot of things!

Answer (score 8):

Basically, it wraps a `byte[]` which it resizes (via copy) as necessary - so local managed heap memory.

Although *technically* that is an implementation detail; it would work exactly the same if it used an unmanaged pointer to unmanaged memory, or a memory-mapped file (although then it wouldn't be able to offer the [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) method).

Comment: your language sounds quite difficult to understand. reading it again and again.

Comment: @Giliweed "unmanaged memory" is stuff inside the process but not part of .NET; you can request chunks of unmanaged memory from the OS, but you need to do more work with it, and use `unsafe` code, etc. Most .NET work doesn't need to explicitly call upon unmanaged memory.